# Is there a way through VBA, to force outlook reminders on all incoming meetings?

Tags: vba, outlook

All my reminders get turned off randomly. Would there be a way to force them on through VBA?

I followed every troubleshooting procedure from 2010 to 2019. All the options in Outlook do not change anything.

I am expecting that when I get a meeting, reminders appear. The little icon next to meetings show no reminder unless I set one myself.

Answer (score 0):

The [IsVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.reminder.isvisible) method of the `Reminder` class returns a Boolean that determines if the reminder is currently visible. Outlook determines the return value of this property based on the state of the current reminder. All active reminders are visible. If `IsVisible` is `True`, the reminder is visible.

```
Sub DismissReminders()  
 'Dismisses any active reminders.  
 Dim objRems As Outlook.Reminders  
 Dim objRem As Outlook.Reminder  
 Dim i As Integer  

 Set objRems = Application.Reminders  
 For i = objRems.Count To 1 Step -1  
  If objRems(i).IsVisible = True Then  
   objRems(i).Dismiss  
  End If  
 Next  

 Set olApp = Nothing  
 Set objRems = Nothing  
 Set objRem = Nothing  
End Sub
```

There is no methods or properties to bring reminders back. The best what you can do is to re-create an appointment item with a reminder set anew:

```
Sub AddAppt()  
 'Adds a new appointment and reminder to the reminders collection  
 Dim objApt As AppointmentItem   
 Set objApt = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)  
 objApt.ReminderSet = True  
 objApt.Subject = "Tuesday's meeting"  
 objApt.Save  
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Eugene, thank you for your help. I am having trouble understanding what your code does. If I copy these blocks into vba outlook and run them, what will happen when a new meeting comes in from a client?